# I want to set Expiry in hset specific key in Redis using redis library in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis, hashset

I am having one hash set in Redis.

```
const redis = require("redis");
let client = redis.createClient('host', 'port', 'password', 'db');

client.hset("emailVerification", "abc@gmail.com", "token_1");
client.hset("emailVerification", "xyz@gmail.com", "token_2");
```

Now, I want to set 24 hours expiry time to **abc@gmail.com** in **emailVerification** hash set. So, after 24 hours it will get expired and removed from the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, Redis doesn't support such operation. The [`EXPIRE`](https://redis.io/commands/expire) command only works on keys and hash operations don't reset the timer.

> The timeout will only be cleared by commands that delete or overwrite the contents of the key, including DEL, SET, GETSET and all the *STORE commands. This means that all the operations that conceptually alter the value stored at the key without replacing it with a new one will leave the timeout untouched. For instance, incrementing the value of a key with INCR, pushing a new value into a list with LPUSH, or altering the field value of a hash with HSET are all operations that will leave the timeout untouched.

This is a simple proof of concept.

```
$ {
> redis-cli hset myhash key1 one
> redis-cli expire myhash 5
> sleep 2
> redis-cli hset myhash key2 two
> sleep 4
> redis-cli dump myhash
> }
(integer) 1
(integer) 1
(integer) 1
(nil)
```

There are a few ways to achieve your goal:

Use the e-mail or some hash based on the e-mail as a key, for example SHA1 hash of `abc@gmail.com` is `c0d0a32c405c68cb538e3891a3e3bce98887f012`:

```
SET emailVerificationc0d0a32c405c68cb538e3891a3e3bce98887f012 token1
EXPIRE  emailVerificationc0d0a32c405c68cb538e3891a3e3bce98887f012 86400
```

or add the expiration as a metadata to your hash, you'd have to store some JSON or other structured form instead of a plain token:

```
HSET myhash abc@gmail.com '{"token":"token1", "expiration": "20190205T09:00"}'
```

Then you can set up some automatic process to clean up old entries. And also check the expiration when trying to verify an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is not possible to put expiration for **hashKey**, You can put top label key expiration using.

```
BoundValueOperations boundOperations = redisTemplate.boundValueOps("Key");
boundOperations.expire("Key", TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```